# Does a current-carrying have an electric field around it?

Tags: electric-fields, electric-current, charge

Assume we have fairly long electric wire. It is far away from the battery. There is a piece of paper next to wire. I am guessing that this piece of paper should get polarized and attracted to the wire. Here is the reason. Charges moving in the wire appear closer together to the electrons and protons in the piece of paper due to speed to electric field propagation. I specifically would like to avoid language of magnetic field and also special relativity theory in order to keep discussion simple. Electrons in the wire that are not moving are getting polarized reducing effect of moving charges. But do they get polarized enough to completely negate it? Are there any experiments to confirm it or to deny it?

**Update**

As I read more about this issue, many people answer that there should be difference in the potential (hence electric fields for electrons to flow). I would like to avoid this part, I intended to ask different question. My question could be restated. Assume we have very big ring made out superconductor. We induce current in this ring, it should persist forever and there should not be any difference in potential. Would there be electric field near this superconductor? Would piece of paper be attracted?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "_Electrons in the wire that are not moving are getting polarized reducing effect of moving charges_"?

Comment: I thought not all electrons are moving in the wire? Some electrons are free to move and some are tightly bound to the nucleus and are not moving with the current. Am I wrong?

Comment: You're talking about the inner shell electrons as "not moving"?

Comment: @josephh probably